# Splitting column text by delimiter into multiple different columns in R

Tags: r, etl, reshape

I have the following problem. I have to split the text below into separate columns. The data is extracted by web scraping and I need to transform it to analyze it. As an example I have copied one row from which I will only need "id":357 and "slug":"journalism/audio" as an information. Do you know how can I transform it in R? The code below is from df column:

```
{"id":357,"name":"Audio","analytics_name":"Audio","slug":"journalism/audio","position":1,"parent_id":13,"parent_name":"Journalism","color":1228010,"urls":{"web":{"discover":"http://www.kickstarter.com/discover/categories/journalism/audio"}}}
```

[A screenshot sample table of the data I want to transform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byUkF.png)

Answer (score 1):

Starting with a string like this

```
stri
[1] "\"id\":357,\"name\":\"Audio\",\"analytics_name\":\"Audio\",\"slug\":\"journalism/audio\",\"position\":1,\"parent_id\":13,\"parent_name\":\"Journalism\",\"color\":1228010,\"urls\":{\"web\":{\"discover\":\"http://www.kickstarter.com/discover/categories/journalism/audio"
```

First `strsplit` the string into chunks by comma and remove the quotes

```
d <- gsub( "\"","", strsplit(stri, ",")[[1]] )
[1] "id:357"
[2] "name:Audio"
[3] "analytics_name:Audio"
[4] "slug:journalism/audio"
[5] "position:1"
[6] "parent_id:13"
[7] "parent_name:Journalism"
[8] "color:1228010"
[9] "urls:{web:{discover:http://www.kickstarter.com/discover/categories/journalism/audio"
```

Finally build the dataframe

```
dat <- data.frame( strsplit( d[grep("^id|^slug",d)], ":" ) )[2,]

colnames( dat ) <- data.frame( strsplit( d[grep("^id|^slug",d)], ":" ) )[1,]
dat
   id             slug
2 357 journalism/audio
```

##### Data

```
stri <- "\"id\":357,\"name\":\"Audio\",\"analytics_name\":\"Audio\",\"slug\":\"journalism/audio\",\"position\":1,\"parent_id\":13,\"parent_name\":\"Journalism\",\"color\":1228010,\"urls\":{\"web\":{\"discover\":\"http://www.kickstarter.com/discover/categories/journalism/audio"
```

Comment: Thank you, that solution worked for my table.

Answer (score 1):

Going off of the one line of data you've supplied here, something like this perhaps?

```
library(magrittr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

#Toy data.
df <- data.frame(category = '{"id":357,"name":"Audio","analytics_name":"Audio","slug":"journalism/audio","position":1,"parent_id":13,"parent_name":"Journalism","color":1228010,"urls":{"web":{"discover":"http://www.kickstarter.com/discover/categories/journalism/audio"}}}')
df[2, ] <- df[1, ] 


df %>% 
  mutate(ucol = row_number()) %>%
  separate_rows(category, sep = ",") %>% 
  mutate(category = str_replace_all(category, '[\\"\\{\\}]', "")) %>% 
  filter(str_detect(category, "^id|^slug")) %>%
  separate(category, sep = ":", into = c("key", "val")) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = key, values_from = val)

# # A tibble: 2 × 3
#    ucol id    slug            
#   <int> <chr> <chr>           
# 1     1 357   journalism/audio
# 2     2 357   journalism/audio
```

Comment: Thank you, that solution was really helpful to me. In the future I will try to provide better data for testing. Your code helped me build up my knowledge for pipe using and transforming data into meaningful information.

Comment: @user16268585 you're welcome!!